# How to fix a circular dependency?

Tags: c++, qt

I have some compilation error in Qt because of a circular dependency but I don't know how to fix it.

Here are the code samples:

`QMdiSubWindowMod.h`:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
[...]
#include "fenetreedition.h"

class QMdiSubWindowMod : public QMdiSubWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QMdiSubWindowMod(QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0);
    [...]
    void getPtrFenetreEdition(FenetreEdition* fen); //get error here in the second case
    ~QMdiSubWindowMod();
private:
    [...]
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
    FenetreEdition *m_ptrFenetreEdition;
};
```

`QMdiSubWindowMod.cpp`:

```
#include "qmdisubwindowmod.h"

QMdiSubWindowMod::QMdiSubWindowMod(QWidget * parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags)
    : QMdiSubWindow(parent, flags)
{
}

QMdiSubWindowMod::~QMdiSubWindowMod()
{
}

void QMdiSubWindowMod::closeEvent (QCloseEvent *event)
{
    [...]
    m_ptrFenetreEdition->onSubWindowClose();
}

[...]

void QMdiSubWindowMod::getPtrFenetreEdition(FenetreEdition* fen)
{
    m_ptrFenetreEdition = fen; //and here too for the second case
}
```

The way I call it:

`FenetreEdition.h`:

```
#include "qmdisubwindowmod.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
[...]
```

`FenetreEdition.cpp`:

```
QMdiSubWindowMod *onglet = new QMdiSubWindowMod(m_centralArea);
[...]
onglet->getPtrFenetreEdition(&this);
```

---

Here are the error showed in the compilator (Qt Creator):

```
C2061: Syntax error: identifier 'FenetreEdition' //on method void getPtrFenetreEdition(FenetreEdition* fen);

C2143: Syntax error: missing ';' before '*' //on FenetreEdition *m_ptrFenetreEdition;

C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. note c++ does not support default-int //on FenetreEdition *m_ptrFenetreEdition;
```

I can't remove the include in FenetreEdition because I need this class to create the QMdiSubWindowMod and i can't remove the include in QMdiSubWindowMod because I need the FenetreEdition pointer to call method on some points.

How to fix it? Thank in advance for your answers!

Comment: Search the internet for "include guards".

Comment: Where is the type FenetreEdition defined?  It isn't defined in any of the code you shared.  With that said, forward declarations are your friend.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That wouldn't actually help here.

Comment: Also search the internet for "c++ forward declaration".

Comment: @Lotharyx It is defined in FenetreEdition.cpp and .h

Comment: Yep, that's a circular dependency all right.  clcto's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you only use a pointer to `FenetreEdition` in `QMdiSubWindowMod.h`. In this case you can forward declare the class instead of including the header. Then in the `.cpp` file you include the header.

QMdiSubWindowMod.h:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
 [...]
class FenetreEdition;
```

Comment: Sorry, it'll not work, I do use some methods of FenetreEdition in my QMdiSubWindowMod class.

Comment: @Ticki you can still use the methods in the `.cpp` file if you include the header there (but it looks like you might need include guards)

Comment: @Ticki, that is not a problem. Make sure you `#include "fenetreedition.h"` in the .cpp file.